# Is there a way to improve performance of mysql events executions?

Tags: mysql, performance, events

I have a MySQL DB with 2 millions data (rows/day) per day in a table which called flows. I wrote a transaction to read and summarize data from this table to write into temp tables which here called top_tcp_ports and top_udp_ports. When I ran below transaction queries on Mysql console usually takes 30s or less to process and insert data to those two tables (top_tcp_ports & top_udp_ports). But on contrary, when MySQL event scheduler run this transaction, it takes 7 minutes to process whole transaction. This event run every 1 hour. The performance and timing here are considering.

```
DELIMITER |
    CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS top_tcp_udp_ports_hourly
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR starts CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  
    DO
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO messages(message,created_at) VALUES('Start Event Execution Log ....',NOW());

        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS top_tcp_ports
        (
        time_stamp datetime,
        tcp_port mediumint(8) signed,
        octetsTotal bigint(20) unsigned,
        packetTotal bigint(20) unsigned
        )ENGINE=MyISAM;

        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS top_udp_ports
        (
        time_stamp datetime,
        udp_port mediumint(8) signed,
        octetsTotal bigint(20) unsigned,
        packetTotal bigint(20) unsigned
        )ENGINE=MyISAM;

        start transaction;

        SET @v1 :=  (select max(saved_max_id ) from saved_id);

        INSERT INTO top_tcp_ports (time_stamp, tcp_port, octetsTotal, packetTotal)
        SELECT (timestamp(res2.date, maketime(res2.hour,00,00))), res2.tcp_port, res2.octetsTotal, res2.packetTotal from
        (SELECT dt as date, hr as hour, tcp_port, sum(byt) as octetsTotal, sum(pkt) as packetTotal from
            (
                (SELECT -1 as tcp_port, sum(packetTotalCount+reversePacketTotalCount) as pkt, sum(octetTotalCount+reverseOctetTotalCount) as byt, date(CONVERT_TZ(flowEndMilliseconds,'UTC','SYSTEM')) as dt, hour(CONVERT_TZ(flowEndMilliseconds,'UTC','SYSTEM')) as hr FROM flows where protocol = 6 and CONVERT_TZ(flowEndMilliseconds,'UTC','SYSTEM')<DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') and (SELECT @v1) < id group by dt, hr)
            union
                (SELECT srcport as tcp_port, sum(packetTotalCount+reversePacketTotalCount) as pkt, sum(octetTotalCount+reverseOctetTotalCount) as byt, date(CONVERT_TZ(flowEndMilliseconds,'UTC','SYSTEM')) as dt, hour(CONVERT_TZ(flowEndMilliseconds,'UTC','SYSTEM')) as hr FROM flows where protocol = 6 and CONVERT_TZ(flowEndMilliseconds,'UTC','SYSTEM')<DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') and (SELECT @v1) < id group by srcport, dt, hr having byt > 1048576)
            union
                (SELECT  dstport as tcp_port, sum(packetTotalCount+reversePacketTotalCount) as pkt, sum(octetTotalCount+reverseOctetTotalCount) as byt, date(CONVERT_TZ(flowEndMilliseconds,'UTC','SYSTEM')) as dt, hour(CONVERT_TZ(flowEndMilliseconds,'UTC','SYSTEM')) as hr FROM flows where protocol = 6 and CONVERT_TZ(flowEndMilliseconds,'UTC','SYSTEM')<DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') and (SELECT @v1) < id group by dstport, dt, hr having byt > 1048576)
            ) as res
        group by tcp_port, dt, hr) as res2;
        INSERT INTO messages(message,created_at) VALUES('Mid_1 Event Execution Log ....',NOW());

        INSERT INTO top_udp_ports (time_stamp, udp_port, octetsTotal, packetTotal)
        SELECT (timestamp(res3.date, maketime(res3.hour,00,00))), res3.udp_port, res3.octetsTotal, res3.packetTotal from
        (SELECT dt as date, hr as hour, udp_port, sum(byt) as octetsTotal, sum(pkt) as packetTotal from
            (
                (SELECT -1 as udp_port, sum(packetTotalCount+reversePacketTotalCount) as pkt, sum(octetTotalCount+reverseOctetTotalCount) as byt, date(CONVERT_TZ(flowEndMilliseconds,'UTC','SYSTEM')) as dt, hour(CONVERT_TZ(flowEndMilliseconds,'UTC','SYSTEM')) as hr FROM flows where protocol = 17 and CONVERT_TZ(flowEndMilliseconds,'UTC','SYSTEM')<DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') and (SELECT @v1) < id group by dt, hr)
            union
                (SELECT srcport as udp_port, sum(packetTotalCount+reversePacketTotalCount) as pkt, sum(octetTotalCount+reverseOctetTotalCount) as byt, date(CONVERT_TZ(flowEndMilliseconds,'UTC','SYSTEM')) as dt, hour(CONVERT_TZ(flowEndMilliseconds,'UTC','SYSTEM')) as hr FROM flows where protocol = 17 and CONVERT_TZ(flowEndMilliseconds,'UTC','SYSTEM')<DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') and (SELECT @v1) < id group by srcport,dt,hr having byt > 1048576)
            union
                (SELECT  dstport as udp_port, sum(packetTotalCount+reversePacketTotalCount) as pkt, sum(octetTotalCount+reverseOctetTotalCount) as byt, date(CONVERT_TZ(flowEndMilliseconds,'UTC','SYSTEM')) as dt, hour(CONVERT_TZ(flowEndMilliseconds,'UTC','SYSTEM')) as hr FROM flows where protocol = 17 and CONVERT_TZ(flowEndMilliseconds,'UTC','SYSTEM')<DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') and (SELECT @v1) < id group by dstport,dt,hr having byt > 1048576)
            ) as res
        group by udp_port, dt, hr) as res3;
        INSERT INTO messages(message,created_at) VALUES('Mid_2 Event Execution Log ....',NOW());

        SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
        update saved_id set saved_max_id=IFNULL((select max(id) from flows where id> (SELECT @v1) and CONVERT_TZ(flowEndMilliseconds,'UTC','SYSTEM')<DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')),(SELECT @v1)) where row_id=1;

        commit; 

        INSERT INTO messages(message,created_at) VALUES('End Event Execution Log ....',NOW());

    END |
    DELIMITER ;
```

The Message table here used for tracking the process of event level.

> The question is how can I improve performance of MySQL events
>   scheduling or boost it up ?
>
> Is there any body face this problem?

Comment: Why do you think `EVENT` is the bottleneck?  Personally, I'd attribute any bottlenecks to the temp tables!

Comment: @bishop because I tested step by step this transaction, the Message table logs the step of execution level of this transaction. The logged time in this table shows execution of event scheduler take times longer than running in consol. Also {show processlist} and {innotop command} shows execution time of every query of event.

Comment: @bishop thank you, you right bottleneck is not event scheduler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect `@v1` is the problem.  Please add `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` *inside* the stored procedure to see how it is working *there*.  Then do likewise *outside* the SP.  I am guessing the `EXPLAINs` will be different, and hopefully informative.

Will these speed it up?

```
CONVERT_TZ(flowEndMilliseconds,'UTC','SYSTEM') <
    DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
-->
flowEndMilliseconds < CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 'SYSTEM', 'UTC')
```

and

```
AND ( SELECT  @v1) < id
```

Plus add

```
INDEX(protocol, flowEndMilliseconds)
-->
AND @v1 < id
```

Comment: Thank you, I modified my queries plus change DB engine to InnoDB, and used partitioning. I get stunning performance on execution event.

Comment: it takes about 10 seconds :) I am going to optimize again the queries in order to record to 4 seconds.

Comment: "I suspect `@v1` is the problem.... I'm guessing the `EXPLAIN`s will be different..." Why?  Your intuition seems spot on, and I'm struggling to understand how you intuited this.

Comment: I could be smug and say "years of experience".  Or I could be serious...  I have seen cases where the optimizer fails to do a logical optimization (eg, use an obvious index) when there is an `@variable` involved.